# Multiple OpenLayers maps in Ionic Vue app

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, openlayers

We're building an app using Ionic 6 / Vue 3 / Capacitor as our framework. On one of the pages we need to display a form which, among other inputs, contain 2 map components. The user can tap to pinpoint a geographical location in each of the maps. This is our map component:

```
<template>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked" color="tertiary" style="margin-bottom: 10px"
      >{{ controlLabel }} (Tap to choose position)</ion-label
    >
    <div class="mapBox">
      <div
        :id="'map'+randomId"
        class="map"
        @click="getCoord($event)"
      ></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ion-label color="tertiary" position="stacked">{{
        $lang.Lengdegrad
      }}</ion-label>
      <ion-input
        v-model="lon"
        @change="setMarker($event)"
        :controlIdLat="controlIdLat"
        :data-value="valueLat"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <ion-label color="tertiary" position="stacked">{{
        $lang.Breddegrad
      }}</ion-label>
      <ion-input
        v-model="lat"
        @change="setMarker($event)"
        :controlIdLon="controlIdLon"
        :data-value="valueLon"
      />
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { IonInput, IonItem, IonLabel } from "@ionic/vue";

import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import Feature from "ol/Feature";
import Point from "ol/geom/Point";
import { Style, Icon } from "ol/style";
import { OSM, Vector as VectorSource } from "ol/source";
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";
import { fromLonLat, toLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import XYZ from "ol/source/XYZ";
import "ol/ol.css";
import PinImg from "../../resources/icons8-pin-48.png";

import { Geolocation } from "@capacitor/geolocation";

export default defineComponent({
  props: [
    "controlLabel",
    "controlIdLat",
    "controlIdLon",
    "lonLatFields",
    "valueLat",
    "valueLon",
    "setStartMarker",
  ],
  components: {
    IonInput,
    IonItem,
    IonLabel,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      mainMap: null,
      lat: null,
      lon: null,
      pinLayer: null,
      pinFeat: null,
      $lang: this.$lang,
      isOnline: this.$isOnline,
      isVisible: false,
      randomId: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5),
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("randomid",this.randomId)
    this.source = new VectorSource();
    setTimeout(async () => {
        if (document.readyState === "loading") {
          document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded",
            await this.getLocation()
          );
        } else {
          await this.getLocation();
        }
      this.myMap();
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.setStartMarker) {
          this.setMarker();
        }
        view.setCenter(fromLonLat([this.lon, this.lat]));
      });
    }, 100);
  },
  methods: {
    async getLocation() {
      const position = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      this.lat = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
      this.lon = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
    },
    getCoord(event) {
      let lonlat = toLonLat(this.mainMap.getEventCoordinate(event));
      this.lat = lonlat[1].toFixed(3);
      this.lon = lonlat[0].toFixed(3);
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.setMarker();
      });
    },
    myMap() {
      this.mainMap = new Map({
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
          }),
          new TileLayer({
            source: new XYZ({
              url: "https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_gmaps?layers=sjokartraster&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}",
              attributions:
                '<a href="http://www.kartverket.no/">Kartverket</a>',
            }),
          }),
          (this.pinLayer = new VectorLayer({
            source: new VectorSource({
              features: [],
            }),
            style: new Style({
              image: new Icon({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                anchorYUnits: "pixels",
                src: PinImg,
              }),
            }),
          })),
        ],
        target: "map" + this.randomId,
        view: view,
      });
      console.log("map", this.mainMap);
    },
    setMarker() {
      let p = new Point(fromLonLat([this.lon, this.lat]));
      console.log("setmarker", p);
      if (!this.pinLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length) {
        this.pinFeat = new Feature({
          geometry: p,
        });
        this.pinLayer.getSource().addFeature(this.pinFeat);
      } else {
        this.pinFeat.setGeometry(p);
      }

      let vals = {
        [this.controlIdLat]: this.lat,
        [this.controlIdLon]: this.lon,
      };
      this.$emit("input", vals);
      console.log(p.getCoordinates());
      view.setCenter(p.getCoordinates());
    },
  },
});
const view = new View({
  center: fromLonLat([13.486, 68.131]),
  zoom: 10,
  constrainResolution: true,
});
</script>

<style scoped>
div.map {
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.mapBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
}
</style>
```

Testing in the browser, this kind of works. The user can tap each of the two maps and two separate locations will be saved to the variables. However, when panning or zooming one of the maps, the other one follows so that they both show exactly the same map area.

As you can see, I've tried assigning a random id to each map to separate them from each other. That didn't work.

Testing on an Android phone, only the latter of the two maps are displayed. The first `mainMap` is left undefined.

My guess is that if I can figure out the first nuisance, then the second problem will also be solved. Any tips?

**Edit:** I tried making a new identical map component and use one for each map. Now the maps work as expected in the browser, being controlled separately. However the first map is still undefined on Android.

Comment: i would ask why do you have two maps on one page in a mobile app? I would imagine that it is not that good of a user experience. You can probably solve the problem by creating on map component and let the user click a button to display the component, like a map picker

Comment: The reason for one of the maps being undefined was that `await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();` was called twice (one time in each map component). This apparently breaks the response on one of them. I've changed the code to getCurrentPosition in the parent component as a global property, then `watch()` for it to change and then pan the maps to the right location.

Comment: @AaronSaunders I think it works quite well with the two maps, actually. But ultimately it is a decision for my customer, so I might have to change it to a map picker anyway.

Comment: Still haven't figured out why I need two identical components, though. I tried importing the original component twice with two different names, but it still didn't work. Panning and zooming one still affected both of them. Isn't Vue supposed to containerize all components?

Comment: if you post a working example I can take a deeper look

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it a lot! I'm on a tight deadline though, so I'll just have to leave it like it is for now.